# How do you use Ember.js addons?

Tags: ember.js

I'm evaluating Ember.js for possible use in an upcoming project. I want to see now it fares with a long list of items, so I tried to installed the ember-list-view.

I ran the command:

`ember install:addon ember-list-view`

The syntax seems to have changed, so I ran

`ember install ember-list-view`

That activates npm, which downloaded the package successfully. I can see it in node_modules. Then per the documentation I created the following:

templates/test.hbs:

```
{{#view 'list-view' items=model height=500 rowHeight=50 width=500}}
  {{name}}
{{/view}}
```

routes/test.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

// define index route and return some data from model
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var items = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
      items.push({name: "Item " + i});
    }
    return items;
  }
});
```

I added the route in router.js. When I go to the page, nothing shows up. According to Ember Inspector, the right template was being used and the data was there. A check on `Ember.ListView` in the console yield undefined.

Is there something more that needs to be done to bring in the code? Searches in the Ember and Ember-CLI documentation yielded no answer.

Comment: are you actually on the test route?  Will you include your router as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a problem with the list-view documentation.

There are two issues here:

1. The `{{view}}` helper is not a block helper (as far as I know. FYI a block helper is a helper that begins with `{{#some-key-word}}` and ends with `{{/some-key-word}}`) - You can't wrap content in it and have that content displayed in the view.
2. The `list-view` expects the property `content` not `items`

When you change the code to the following:

`{{view 'list-view' content=model height=500 rowHeight=50 width=500}}`

It works a little bit better (e.g. you can inspect the page and see item views being created) - but still not what you're expecting.

When you change the `view` keyword to the `ember-list` keyword (which ember-list-view registers as a helper) - everything works.

```
{{#ember-list items=model height=500 rowHeight=50 width=500}}
  {{name}}
{{/ember-list}}
```

Comment: There are issues and PRs logged against the project the help clear up the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sadly, the list view seems to be broken: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/80776822/Development%20Server.png.

Comment: Nevermind. I just failed to include the required CSS.